# HP laptop doesn't charge battery unless OFF

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery, hp-laptop

I have an HP Omen 15" and it doesn't charge the battery when the computer is on. If I connect the charger the symbol of the battery appears as “connected” for around 5 seconds and then it shows that it's working from the battery.

But the weird thing is that if the laptop is shut down or suspended then the battery does charge.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It could be an “omen” that the power adapter is bad. Have you tried another one by any chance? The power adapter may not be capable of powering the laptop and charging the battery at the same time.

Comment: Yes, tried at the store, it happens the same with other adapters.

Comment: Try a BIOS update and possibly a BIOS reset just to make sure any relevant settings are reset. Other than that, the motherboard has apparently gone bad. I guess there is a small chance it is the battery.

Comment: BIOS update already done before the post, nothing changed. BIOS reset how can I do that and what consequences might have for the computer? What's weird is that it does charge when suspended/shutdown, and not when using the computer. If it's a motherboard problem only solution is to take the computer to HP?